# Ionic 3.9.5 Reactive Forms not working when virtual keyboard is displayed

Tags: ionic3, ionic4

I am trying to create a simple login form like the example here https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/10/angular-6-reactive-forms-validation-example in Ionic 3.9.5. Then I've noticed an issue I have never encountered before. When the virtual keyboard is open on an emulator or mobile device it does not fire the event instantly when I click on the submit button or just type in the textboxes. I have to manually close the virtual keyboard by clicking outside in order for the page to get updated. What's been bugging me is that I only encounter this when working on mobile devices. This works fine on web and I've tested on a fresh app it and it works as well. So now I'm not sure if it's only encountered with the version im using.